# Retrieve data extension from different bussines unit using AMPScript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have 2 business units. In one of them there is a landing-page and on another data extension. Can I retrieve data from data extension on my page? Standard function like Lookup Row() doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This can work if you set this up with the data extension in Parent BU, and the landing page in a child BU.
Move the data extension to "shared" and you should be able to target it using the ENT. prefix in AMPScript.

like so:

```
Lookup("ENT.myDE","email","subscriberkey",_subscriberkey)
```

Should this not be feasible, because your setup is different, then AMPScript cannot help and you have to setup an installed package for API communication, and use SSJS on your cloudpage to write API-based Retrieve calls.

Comment: And if it's a business unit at the siblings level. Can I do this without SSJS?

Comment: the data extensions need to be in shared folder, which means they technically become associated to the parent, no matter where they were shared from. If they are shared, ENT. works.